# Get data from a loop and use it in a script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```js
$('.btn[data-toggle=modal]').on('click', function(){
  var $btn = $(this);
  var currentDialog = $btn.closest('.modal-dialog'),
  targetDialog = $($btn.attr('data-target'));;
  if (!currentDialog.length)
    return;
  targetDialog.data('previous-dialog', currentDialog);
  currentDialog.addClass('aside');
  var stackedDialogCount = $('.modal.in .modal-dialog.aside').length;
  if (stackedDialogCount <= 5){
    currentDialog.addClass('aside-' + stackedDialogCount);
  }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    $('.modal').removeClass('aside');
  });
});
```

```css
.modal.in {
  -webkit-perspective: 2000px;
  -moz-perspective: 2000px;
  -ms-perspective: 2000px;
  -o-perspective: 2000px;
  perspective: 2000px;
}
.modal.in .modal-dialog.aside {
  -webkit-transform: -340px;
  -moz-transform: -340px;
  -ms-transform: -340px;
  -o-transform: -340px;
  transform: -340px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(-340px);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(-340px);
  -o-transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(-340px);
  transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(-340px);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.modal.in .modal-dialog.aside.aside-1 {
  -webkit-transform: calc(-300px);
  -moz-transform: calc(-300px);
  -ms-transform: calc(-300px);
  -o-transform: calc(-300px);
  transform: calc(-300px);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(calc(-300px));
  -ms-transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(calc(-300px));
  -o-transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(calc(-300px));
  transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(calc(-300px));
}
.modal.in .modal-dialog.aside.aside-2 {
  -webkit-transform: calc(-260px);
  -moz-transform: calc(-260px);
  -ms-transform: calc(-260px);
  -o-transform: calc(-260px);
  transform: calc(-260px);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(calc(-260px));
  -ms-transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(calc(-260px));
  -o-transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(calc(-260px));
  transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(calc(-260px));
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test-modal">

<div class="modal fade" id="test-modal" data-modal-index="1">
                          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                            <div class="modal-content" style="background: #031035 url(images/logo.png) no-repeat center center fixed;">
                              <div class="modal-header" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align: center;"><strong>EVENT RETURNED:</strong></h4>
                                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <label style="font-size: 15px; color: green;">Fecha:</label>
                                    <p style="text-transform: uppercase; display: inline; padding-left: 18px; padding-right: 18px; font-size: 18px; color: #8a8a8a;"></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <label style="font-size: 15px; color: green;">Agencia:</label>
                                    <p style="text-transform: uppercase; display: inline; padding-left: 18px; padding-right: 18px; font-size: 18px; color: #8a8a8a;">INOP</p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <label style="font-size: 15px; color: green;">Tipo:</label>
                                    <p style="text-transform: uppercase; display: inline; padding-left: 18px; padding-right: 18px; font-size: 18px; color: #8a8a8a;"></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <label style="font-size: 15px; color: green;">Ofensa:</label>
                                    <p style="text-transform: uppercase; display: inline; padding-left: 18px; padding-right: 18px; font-size: 18px; color: #8a8a8a;"</p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <label style="font-size: 15px; color: green;">Lugar:</label>
                                    <p style="text-transform: uppercase; display: inline; padding-left: 18px; padding-right: 18px; font-size: 18px; color: #8a8a8a;"></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-xs-4">
                                    <label style="font-size: 15px; color: green;">Sector:</label>
                                    <p style="text-transform: uppercase; display: inline; padding-left: 18px; padding-right: 18px; font-size: 18px; color: #8a8a8a;"></p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-xs-4">
                                    <label style="font-size: 15px; color: green;">Tipo:</label>
                                    <p style="text-transform: uppercase; display: inline; padding-left: 18px; padding-right: 18px; font-size: 18px; color: #8a8a8a;"></p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-xs-4">
                                    <label style="font-size: 15px; color: green;">ND:</label>
                                    <p style="text-transform: uppercase; display: inline; padding-left: 18px; padding-right: 18px; font-size: 18px; color: #8a8a8a;"></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-xs-4" style="width: 18%;">
                                    <label style="font-size: 15px; color: green;">Descripci&oacute;n:</label>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                                    <p style="text-transform: uppercase; display: inline; font-size: 18px; color: #8a8a8a;">
                                      </p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <label style="font-size: 15px; color: green;">RP:</label>
                                    <p style="text-transform: uppercase; display: inline; padding-left: 18px; padding-right: 18px; font-size: 18px; color: #8a8a8a;"></p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <label style="font-size: 15px; color: green;">RPP:</label>
                                    <p style="text-transform: uppercase; display: inline; padding-left: 18px; padding-right: 18px; font-size: 18px; color: #8a8a8a;"></p>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <label style="font-size: 15px; color: green;">SPE:</label>
                                    <p style="text-transform: uppercase; display: inline; padding-left: 18px; padding-right: 18px; font-size: 18px; color: #8a8a8a;"></p>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <label style="font-size: 15px; color: green;">DISPO:</label><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test-modal-2">Launch Modal 2</button></p>';
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                  <br>
                <br>
              <br>
            <br>
          <br></div>
                        <div class="modal-footer" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      </div>
                   
                      <div class="modal fade" id="test-modal-2" data-modal-index="2">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" ><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title 2</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

```js
$('.btn[data-toggle=modal]').on('click', function(){
  var $btn = $(this);
  var currentDialog = $btn.closest('.modal-dialog'),
  targetDialog = $($btn.attr('data-target'));;
  if (!currentDialog.length)
    return;
  targetDialog.data('previous-dialog', currentDialog);
  currentDialog.addClass('aside');
  var stackedDialogCount = $('.modal.in .modal-dialog.aside').length;
  if (stackedDialogCount <= 5){
    currentDialog.addClass('aside-' + stackedDialogCount);
  }
});

$('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
  var $dialog = $(this);  
  var previousDialog = $dialog.data('previous-dialog');
  if (previousDialog){
    previousDialog.removeClass('aside');
    $dialog.data('previous-dialog', undefined);
  }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  var numero = "#test-modal<?php echo $array1; ?>";
  $(numero).on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
      alert('The modal is about to be hidden.');
  });
});
```

```html
<?php
$i = 0;
if($countdelitos != 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($querydelitos)){
$i++;
$id_delito = $row['id'];
$fecha_delito = $row['fecha'];
?>
<!-- Modal -->
<?php echo'
<div class="modal fade" id="test-modal'.$i.'" data-modal-index="1">';  //Here goes the rest of the modal 1 and 2 (test-modal$i and test-modal-2$i</div> ?>
```

I need a little bit of help here.

So I have $i defined as 0, and that number will be increased in the while loop. What I'm trying to do is use that $i in a js code that will send an alert after you close the modal. So I guess I need to get the data outside the loop and use it in the script

EDIT: Inside the modal 1 there's a button to open the modal 2 (so it's stackable) after the modal 2 opens the modal 1 get's a rotate effect that stays behind but rotated and that work's perfectly but when you close the modal the modal 1 stays rotated and it doesn't not rotate again to the normal position and that's because the '$i' variable. So to discover this problem I made an alert and then I discovered that is not working because of the '$i' variable doesn't know where to use the removeClass function.

Hope you understand better.

Sorry for my poor english, if you don't understand something just say it and I will reply to you

Comment: It might help to show a little more of your code for context. You mean you have several modals being created by the PHP loop? And you want JavaScript to reference each modal's ID?

Comment: How do these two pieces of code relate?  Is the second being emitted inside the loop, or after the loop?  What ends up being emitted to the page?  How specifically is it failing?

Comment: Okey I did, hope you understand now :( sorry for my poor english

Comment: Looking at your code, it seems you could bind the handler to all `div.modal` elements rather than to each specific ID. Would that work? `$('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () { ....`

Comment: Okey so that works with the alert but it doesnt with the removeClass function
`  $('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    $('.modal').removeClass('rotate');
  });`

any idea? @showdev

Comment: I don't see that in your code and it's hard to tell what's going on without a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But I'd suggest using `$(this)` to refer to the element on which the event originated. Also, I'm not sure why there are two `hide.bs.modal` event handlers -- maybe you can combine them.

Comment: @showdev I added more of my code, is not working but maybe you will understand now. Also I'm trying to do this https://codepen.io/maouida/pen/NPGaaN but as I said before isn't closing and I don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original post, I suggest binding the handler once to all `div.modal` elements rather than to each specific ID. Like this:

```
$('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () { ....
```

Then, within that handler, use `$(this)` to refer to the "modal" element on which the event originated. Each modal will fire this same handler upon its "hide.bs.modal" event and will reference itself via `$(this)`.

---

Looking at the code in your latest edit, it seems that you're not handling the `previous-dialog` data correctly when dialogs close. In the [CodePen sample](https://codepen.io/maouida/pen/NPGaaN) you referenced, notice how a jQuery object for the `previous-dialog` gets stored in the `targetDialog`, so that it can be restored when the `targetDialog` closes.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.btn[data-toggle=modal]').on('click', function() {

    var $btn = $(this),
      currentDialog = $btn.closest('.modal-dialog'),
      targetDialog = $($btn.attr('data-target'));

    if (!currentDialog.length) {
      return;
    }

    /**
     * Current dialog gets stored as "previous dialog" in the dialog that's about to open (the target).
     * When the target dialog closes, the previous dialog can be restored to primary position.
     */

    targetDialog.data('previous-dialog', currentDialog);
    currentDialog.addClass('aside');

    var stackedDialogCount = $('.modal.in .modal-dialog.aside').length;
    if (stackedDialogCount <= 5) {
      currentDialog.addClass('aside-' + stackedDialogCount);
    }

  });

  $('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {

    /**
     * Here's where the "previous dialog" gets restored.
     * The dialog that's firing the "hide" event has a "previous dialog" stored in it from when it was opened.
     * That previous dialog gets its "aside" class removed.
     */

    var $dialog = $(this),
      previousDialog = $dialog.data('previous-dialog');

    if (previousDialog) {
      previousDialog.removeClass('aside');
      $dialog.data('previous-dialog', undefined);
    }

  });

});
```

```css
.modal.in {
  -webkit-perspective: 2000px;
  -moz-perspective: 2000px;
  -ms-perspective: 2000px;
  -o-perspective: 2000px;
  perspective: 2000px;
}

.modal.in .modal-dialog.aside {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(-340px);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(-340px);
  -o-transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(-340px);
  transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(-340px);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.modal.in .modal-dialog.aside.aside-1 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(calc(-300px));
  -ms-transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(calc(-300px));
  -o-transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(calc(-300px));
  transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(calc(-300px));
}

.modal.in .modal-dialog.aside.aside-2 {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(calc(-260px));
  -ms-transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(calc(-260px));
  -o-transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(calc(-260px));
  transform: scale(0.8) rotateY(45deg) translateZ(calc(-260px));
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test-modal">Open Modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="test-modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
    
      <div class="modal-header" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align: center;"><strong>EVENT RETURNED:</strong></h4>
      </div>

      <!-- rows removed for brevity -->

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test-modal-2">Launch Modal 2</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="test-modal-2">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test-modal-3">Launch Modal 3</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="test-modal-3">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title 3</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```